# Issue while using browserify with node module

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I want to include the pbkdf2 npm library into my JS/html pages which are just plain Javascript, node is not available.

browserify should have me covered there. I have written a short JS file (main.js) which uses the functionality.

```
var callback = function (err, key) {
    console.log(key);
}


function hashIt(hac, callback)  {
    pbkdf2.pbkdf2(hac, hac, 10000, 32, 'sha256', callback);
    
}
```

I use  browserify to make this into an "includable" JS file

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

The bundle.js file looks OK like browserify did its magic.

I included the bundle.js file inside my HTML pages however I'm not able to access the hashIt function. IS there a special way to include or call the functions inside bundle.js ?

Comment: Is there a reason you'd rather not use the built-in functionality to hash in the browser through crypto.subtle?

Comment: I am using an old ExtJs framework which doesn't know to handle "Promises".

Answer (score 0):

Export your function on the `window` object.

```js
var callback = function (err, key) {
    console.log(key);
}


function hashIt(hac, callback)  {
    pbkdf2.pbkdf2(hac, hac, 10000, 32, 'sha256', callback);   
}

window.hashIt = hashIt;
```

In the browser.

```js
hashIt('test', (err, key) => console.log(key.toString()))
> ��&�`=�&
0q$.��bp�u��<!x���GV�;
```

Screenshot from Chrome.

[image]