# Ext JS and browserify integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs, browserify

Can a browserify bundle.js file be used in ExtJS? If so how is it done and are there any examples?

I've included the bundle file however I am not able to access the content of it.

I'd like to use a Node.js library from within the ExtJS framework.

Comment: Yes, possible. - what have you tried? Share some code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030616/issue-while-using-browserify-with-node-module